# assistance needed with iis rewrite rule in web.config

Tags: iis, asp.net-mvc-4, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I am working with an mvc4 applciation running in IIS 7.5 and I am having trouble with rewrite rules I have set up. The following is my section from the web.config.

```
 <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="RewriteImage">
                <match url="/myassets/([_0-9a-z-]+)/images/category/([_0-9]+)-([_0-9a-z-]+)-([0-9]+)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/myassets/{R:1}/images/category/cat_{R:2}_{R:4}_{R:3}.jpg" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

What I want to do in above url rewrite images to another path.

I supply the following url `https://localhost/myassets/en-uk/images/category/123456-5x10-1_my+image+description.jpg` and expect it to rewrite to `https://localhost/myassets/en-uk/images/category/cat_123456_1_5x10.jpg` but it doesn't.

When I test it in IIS, all works fine, but via the browser the rule never kicks in. I am looking for suggestions as to where I am gone wrong as this is becoming very frustrating!

This is the only rule I have, I tried a simple redirect rule which redirects uppercase url's to lower case urls and this works fine.

One thing I did notice in my web.config, the first rewrite tag has a blue squiggly under saying it its not recognised section of system.webserver.

Application is running in integrated mode.

Comment: How do you know the rule never kicks in? Does the file `https://localhost/myassets/en-uk/images/category/cat_123456_1_5x10.jpg` exist?

Comment: What if you remove `<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />`?

Comment: Makes no difference if I do

Comment: So the picture `https://localhost/myassets/en-uk/images/category/cat_123456_1_5x10.jpg` exists and when you call `https://localhost/myassets/en-uk/images/category/123456-5x10-1_my+image+description.jpg` it doesn't display it, right? What do see instead? What if you use the [Failed Request Tracing tool](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules)?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that your regexp wasn't valid. Note from [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference):

> For example, if a request was made for this URL:
>   http://www.example.com/content/default.aspx?tabid=2&subtabid=3, and a
>   rewrite rule was defined on the site level then: The rule pattern gets the URL string `content/default.aspx` as an input.

That means, that you shouldn't start your regexp with starting slash.

Working example is:

```
<rule name="RewriteImage">
    <match url="myassets/([_0-9a-z-]+)/images/category/([_0-9]+)-([_0-9a-z-]+)-([0-9]+)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/myassets/{R:1}/images/category/cat_{R:2}_{R:4}_{R:3}.jpg" />
</rule>
```